# Overflow auto not working properly with mat-checkbox

Tags: css, angular

Issue: Overflow auto not working properly with mat-checkbox component

Desired behaviour: the scrollbar should not be visible since the max height is not met

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bswmum?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) example

Am I missing something ? Or is there a css fix for this issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post your example here, not on an external site. When the external site changes your question will no longer make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set Overflow to hidden for checkboxes.

```
overflow: hidden
```

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t8wqu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) is the stackblitz.